# Need to pass a variable to remote swf

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a prototype Air for Android application that loads some remote swf files (all created and controlled by me) and I need to be able to pass a variable along to the remote SWF.

Here is a quick break down of how the process currently works:

- The Android app, called Loader, is installed on the device.
- Loader points to my server and finds Player.swf, which it loads into the main stage. Player.swf show a login screen.
- When a user logs in correctly, Player.swf receives an XML response from an API with a list of remote SWF videos to display for the user. Player.swf loops through the XML list and plays each remote SWF, one after the other.

Now, so far, so good. The remote SWF videos load up and play perfectly. But I need to start picking up variables from Player.swf (pulled from the XML response) to use in the remote SWF (things like text strings, user ID's etc)

From all the searching I have done, I believe it is down to the Sandbox environment, as Loader is a compiled application and Player.swf + the remote SWF's are all coming off a server. However, now I am wondering, as Player.swf is the one that has the AS3 code to deal with the XML response, and that is located on the same server as the remote SWF's that are played (and therefore should be the same sandbox?)

I was able to pass a variable along using a URL parameter, but it only works locally and not when I use the Android application.

I found an old blog pot about Sandbox Bridges, but the example file download doesn't work anymore.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in using the parentSandboxBridge function/class to pass along a variable (all examples I have seen deal with passing functions and/or are coded for Flex)

I cannot post any code, as I simply have nothing to show for what I want to achieve (I'm totally stumped on this bit!)

EDIT: I managed to get parameters to pass along (even though it worked locally before, it didnt work with the Loader app > Remote Player > Remote SWF animation combo)

I had to set the application domain context inside Player.swf (seeing as it is on the same server as the remote swf animations, not sure why I needed to do this)

But oddly, I cannot use parent or root to pickup variables?

Comment: can you show how you've tried? if you are loading another SWF to your main SWF than there is data object for URLRequest that you can fill with URLVariables and pass to the load method of Loader.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on HTC Desire running android 2.2.2 and it works what I've put in comment thus the answer is as follows:)

your host needs to define similar:

```
        var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            params["string"] = "ala ma kota";
            params["number"] = 1979;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.data = params;
            request.url = "urlVarsReader.swf";

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        loader.load(request);

        addChild(loader);
```

then loaded content (here urlVarsReader.swf) can read them as follows:

```
        var output:TextField = new TextField();
        addChild(output);
        output.border = true;
        output.width = 320;
        output.height = 240;
        output.wordWrap = true;
        output.multiline = true;
        var p:Object = getParams(this.loaderInfo);
        for (var name:String in p) 
        {
            output.appendText(name + " = " + p[name] + "\n");
        }
```

I have a wrapper method for reading params:

```
    public function getParams(li:LoaderInfo):Object
    {
        try
        {
            var params:Object = li.parameters;
            var pairs:Object = {};
            var key:String;
            for(key in params)
            {
                pairs[key] = String(params[key]);
            }
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            return {error:e.getStackTrace()};
        }
        return pairs;
    }
```

best regards

EDIT:

This works only with local content fails with SecurytyError e.g. SecurityError: Error #2070: Security sandbox violation: caller http://example.com/urlVarsReader.swf?string=ala%20ma%20kota&number=1979 cannot access Stage owned by app:/loadwithparams.swf

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have you tried with urlsVarRead.swf hosted on a remote server?

Comment: Also remember, MY android app is loading a remote swf that loads more remote swfs into it. App > swf (this one supplies the variable) > swf (this one needs to pick it up)

Comment: unfortunately can't load it:( I've googled and people suggested to using HTMLLoader/StageWebView or load it as ByteArray.

Comment: If you see my post edit, you can see i got parameters working between the hosted player.swf and the remote animations, but using a applicationdomain context (weird i know, as they are both on the same server)

Comment: add "try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };" and "try {Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");}catch (e) { };" to the app and add "Security.allowDomain("*");" and "Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");" to the hsoted swf

Comment: The same thing - it doesn't allow for access to stage properties of the host SWF from content SWF. I will search for the resolution - strangely saving to sdcard and loading from it has the same result.

Comment: Look into Sandbox Bridges (which i was doing) as i think that is the way to do it properly. Unfortunatly all documention is pretty rubbish and only uses exmaples of passing functions, not strings (strings can be passed)